# call function in php, little help please

Tags: php

How can I call a function like below:

```
 $display_table="<table><tr><td>FUNCTION_CALL_HERE();</td></tr></table>";
```

I have tried brackets and all, but the function wont get called...

How should I make this work? (syntax problems I think)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there a reason you cannot use string concatenation?  Assuming the output of `FUNCTION_CALL_HERE` is a string.

```
$display_table="<table><tr><td>" . FUNCTION_CALL_HERE() . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $display_table="<table><tr><td>" . FUNCTION_CALL_HERE() . "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
$display_table="<table><tr><td>{FUNCTION_CALL_HERE()}</td></tr></table>";
```

Actually should be:

```
<?php

function asdf() {
return 'this is my string';
}
$f= 'asdf';

echo "Hello {$f()}\n";

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, no this does not work. The braces can only contain a $ variable reference such as multiply dimensioned arrays.

Comment: My first example wasn't quite right - but it is possible to call functions from within strings.